# Rademacher complexity of function class $\{(x,y) \mapsto 1[|yf(x)-\alpha| \ge \beta]$ in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and Rademacher complexity of $F$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, measure-concentration, learning-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable space and let $P$ be a probability distribution on $X \times \{\pm 1\}$. Let $F$ be a function class on $X$, i.e., a collection of (measurable) functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Fix $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\beta > 0$, and cobsider a derived function class on $H := \{\ell_f \mid f \in F\}$ on $X \times \{\pm 1\}$, where for each $f \in F$, the new function $\ell_f:X \times \{\pm 1\} \to \{0,1\}$ is defined by
$$
\ell_f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1,&\mbox{ if }|yf(x)-\alpha| \ge \beta,\\
0,&\mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ be an iid sequence of Rademacher $\pm 1$ random variables, independent of the $x_i$'s and $y_i$, and define

$$
\begin{split}
R_n(F) &:= \mathbb E_{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n}\left[\sup_{f \in F}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i f(x_i)\right]\\
R_n(H) &:= \mathbb E_{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n}\left[\sup_{h \in H}\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i h(x_i,y_i)\right].
\end{split}
$$
Note that $R_n(F)$ (resp. $R_n(H)$) is nothing but the *Rademacher complexity* of $F$ (resp. $H$).

> **Question.** *What is a good upper-bound for $\mathbb E\ R_n(H)$ in terms of $\mathbb E\,R_n(F)$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ ?*

I'm particularly interested in the case where $F := F_{\mathrm{lin}}$, a function class on $\mathbb R^d$ defined by
$$
F_{\mathrm{lin}} := \{x \mapsto x^\top w + b \mid b \in \mathbb R, \,w \in \mathbb R^d\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The following VC dimension bound was established in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/420482/78539),
$$
\mathrm{VCdim}(H) \le 2\cdot \mathrm{VCdim}(\mathrm{SG}(F)),
$$
where $\mathrm{SG}(F) := \{\{x \in X \mid f(x) \le 0\}\}$ is the *subgraph* of $F$.

On the other, hand it's well-known that Rademacher complexity can be bounded via VC dimension like so.
$$
\mathbb E\, R_n(H) \lesssim\sqrt{\dfrac{\mathrm{VCdim}(H)}{n}}.
$$

We conclude that
$$
\mathbb E\,R_n(H) \lesssim \sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathrm{SG}(F))}{n}}.
$$

In particular, because $\mathrm{VCdim}(\mathrm{SG}(F_{\mathrm{lin}})) = d$, we conclude that

$$
\mathbb E\,\widetilde R_n(F_{\mathrm{lin}}) \lesssim \sqrt{\frac{d}{n}}.
$$